# Binding an ObservableCollection of Strings to a ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I am currently trying to grasp the concepts of MVVM. Therefore, I already read several blogs and looked at a few projects. However, I still have no idea how to apply the concept.

Right now, I am trying to bind an ObservableCollection of String values to a ListBox so that their values are listed line by line. My **ViewModel** currently looks like this:

```
namespace TestApp.ViewModel
{
    class StatusViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _newMsg;
        private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _history = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public string Print
        {
            get { return _newMsg; }
            set
            {
                _newMsg = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("History");
                AddToHistory(_newMsg);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> History
        {
            get { return _history; }
        }

        private void AddToHistory(string item)
        {
            if (!_history.Contains(item))
                _history.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

namespace TestApp.ViewModel
{
    public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In the View, I want to bind the ListBox to `History`. Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.View.StatusView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModel" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:StatusView x:Key="statusView"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource statusView}">
        <GroupBox Header="StatusView">
            <ListBox x:Name="StatusListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding History, Source={StaticResource statusView}}"/>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I start the TestApp, I need to access the instance of my `StatusViewModel` in order to add a string to my ObservableCollection. I am wondering how this is done:

```
using TestApp.ViewModel;

namespace TestApp.Controller
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private void StartTestApp()
        {
            // from where do I get my 'statObj' in order to do:
            statObj.Print = "something";
        }
    }
}
```

How do I bind the ObservableCollection of Strings in my StatusViewModel object to the Listbox?

**UPDATE:**

Thank you all for the great comments! Now, I understand that I need to hold an instance of my ViewModel, in order to access it from both the *View* **and** the *Controller*. However, I am still struggling with how to do that in the right way.## Heading ##

For now, I started with creating the instance in the code-behind of the user control. Although it is working, I don't like that I have to reference the ViewModel in my View. I thought, it is the whole point of MVVM **not** to do that.

Moreover, I am wondering how I can access my newly instantiated StatusViewModel status outside of the View, e.g. in a different namespace named *Controller*.

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using TestApp.ViewModel;

namespace TestApp.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction Logic for StatusView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StatusView : UserControl
    {
        public StatusView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new StatusViewModel();
        }

        public TestApp.ViewModel.StatusViewModel State
        {
            get { return (DataContext as TestApp.ViewModel.StatusViewModel); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Binding will work on this instance of `Status`: `<vm:Status x:Key="status"/>` and for testing you create **different instance of `Status`** and change `Print` on that. They are not the same objects

Comment: That makes sense! But how could I edit the existent status object in my `StartTestApp` method? My start method is in a different namespace, which is named `TestApp.Controller`.

Comment: You need to get hold of that instance.  Depends on your design.  Some people use frameworks that include view model locators.  I usually define my VMs as resources in app.xaml then *bind them to each other*, so VM X has a reference to VM Y.  Some people construct them in the view's constructor so they have a reference to it.  However you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change your XAML to this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.View.Status"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestApp.ViewModel" mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:Status />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Status">
        <ListBox x:Name="StatusListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding History}"/>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

And the code to access your viemodel should contain this:

```
Status status = DataContext as Status;
if (status != null)
   status.Print = "Hello";
```

Then it seems to work:
[image]

When you want to access the Status instance of this user control, add a property to the user control:

```
public TestApp.ViewModel.Status State // Status gives probably naming conflict
{ 
    get
    {
        return (DataContext as TestApp.ViewModel.Status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Unfortunately, there is still no message shown in my ListBox :(

Comment: You have not set the DataContext. Oh, you did... sorry.

Comment: Where exactly should I add the `if (DataContext != null) ...` ?

Comment: That null check is incorrect.  Should be `var thisIsHackyAnyhowSoWhyDoICareIAskYou = DataContext as Status; if(thisIsHackyAnyhowSoWhyDoICareIAskYou != null) thisIsHackyAnyhowSoWhyDoICareIAskYou.Print = "DERP HACK ALERT";`

Comment: For example, in the code-behind of the user control for example. At least, you need a way to reference the instantiated user control in some way. For example, from the Window where you put your user control on.

Comment: @Will: Yes, you are right, but you see in the XAML that the DataContext is assigned to a Status instance. When DataContext is not null, it will be a Status instance in this example. But I agree that your way of checking is better for maintainability and is better practise. Therefore, I have updated the example.

Comment: I still haven't fully understood how to apply the concept. I just updated my question. Maybe I should use a framework such as Light MVVM, but I do not want to pay for those expensive tutorials...

Comment: I've updated the code with an example how to access the Status object.

Comment: Thank you again! It's getting confusing, because I named both the View and the ViewModel with the same name _Status_. I just updated my code and also changed the class names to _StatusView_ and _StatusViewModel_, because I think that that's why we talk past each other. I am still wondering how to get an instance of _StatusViewModel_ into my Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public ObservableCollection<string> History
{
    get { return _history; }
}
private void AddToHistory(string item)
{
    if (!History.Contains(item)) History.Add(item);
}
```